# Macbook Air 2015 good for iOS developing?

Tags: apple

Is MacBook Air Early 2015 edition with 1.6 GHz Intel Core i5, 4GB memory 1600 MHz DDR3, 1.5GB graphics card, and 120GB SSD hard drive good learning and developing iOS apps using swift programming language?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly without knowing what kind and size of apps you're building. My initial temptation is to say it'll probably work for learning, but isn't ideal; however, without more info it's really hard to say.

Comment: im still a beginner

Answer (score 1):

For a professional it is ok. It's still capable of compiling quite quickly. For a beginner, it will be more than enough. People use way weaker laptops and still make it. Just make sure all of the software you're using is supported on MacOS and you'll be good to go.